# Can I create an array prior to running a method?

Tags: objective-c

```
int indexOfArray = 0;


-(void)pushNumber:(double)number{
    if(self.numArray == NULL)
        self.numArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    indexOfArray = self.numArray.count;
    [self.numArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:number] atIndex:(indexOfArray)];
    indexOfArray--;
}
```

This is currently what part of my code looks like for a push method I am doing. The way I want to set it up is to push the number to the end of the array because that will allow me to pop the first number I pushed in using `lastObject`. I have experience in Java, but I have been making my way to Objective-C on my own, hence I am not sure if what I am doing is right. What I do know right now is that ever time this method runs `indexOfArray` will reset its count, and I don't want that. I want to be able to initialize the array before the method so I can have a constant size to start with which I can then decrement each time this method is called.

To be clear, this is for a calculator app I am making in my free time. I want to be able to reset the `indexOfArray` every the user presses a number after an operator, when the user presses clear, or when the user presses the `=` button.

Comment: You may be more efficient using NSMutableArray which provide a method addObject and is generally easier to handle this kind of stack behavior.see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/

Comment: Then why don't you use `removeObjectAtIndex:` and `addObject:`?

Comment: or `removeLastObject` for the delete key

Comment: minor stylistic nitpicks: Use `nil` instead of `NULL` to represent a nil object, and (if you're using a recent xcode version) @(number) instead of [NSNumber numberWithDouble:number].

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an equivalent of a constructor in Java, override `-init`. Example:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init]
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.numArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    return self;
}
```

However, as others have said, if your class is just a stack, it might be easier just to use an NSMutableArray, as it has methods for stack-like access.

Also, if `int indexOfArray = 0;` is really defined next to a method as it looks, you've got a global variable not an instance (/member) variable, which you might think you're declaring.

(if this stuff is new to you, I recommend reading Apple's [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210)  and [Programming With Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210) articles)

Comment: Yes, I want it to be a global variable because I need to be able to access it again. The reason is because I want to do a first in first out queue using. If I make the `indexOfArray` local to that method, then it is going to be disposed of after each method call and I won't be able to decrement the index and insert the numbers from the end of the array to the front. Please correct my idea if I am wrong. I want to sort the integers being passed in from the end of the list so I can use the method `removeLastObject` to get the item out in the order they were put in.

Comment: I would also like to add that if I try and create the area prior to the method (eg globally) I get this: `NSMutableArray* testArray = [NSMutableArray array]; Initializer element is not compile time constant`

Comment: Why not make it an instance variable?

Comment: (`instancetype` is redundant for `init`. Clang already treats `alloc` and `init` as returning the type of their reciever.)

Comment: If I make it an instance variable I lose it after each method call correct? So if that happens, I can't keep track of the numbers if multiple numbers are being entered into the calculator.

Comment: No, you loose it when the object is deallocated. I recommend reading the linked articles if you're not sure about this stuff. It'll save you a *lot* of time.